# Firebase Database rules - wildcard for dynamic key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have this usecase where I want to give permission to other users read data under my ID key only if there is a key === to their Id.

Let’s say I have user 123 and 456 who writes json object under “

```
orders-
              I
               -123
                        I
                         -456
```

And I want only user 123 and 456 to be able to read the 456 nodes. With the rules that I provide only 123 is able to read the node:

```
"orders": {
    "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid  === $uid || root.child('orders').child($uid).child(auth.uid).exists()",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null",
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can anyone help me with this, please?

EDIT: Two screenshots of the simulator

[image]

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that we have no way to know what the data in your screenshot means. And that the ..... are making the middle paragraph needlessly hard to read. You might want to replace the screenshot with the actual JSON, which you can get by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). It would also be really useful to see the minimal code of the read that you want to allow, but that is failing; with as many values hardcoded as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, you’re right about the ....  and replaced it, now I think is more readable. I’m trying this in the rules simulator, because I didn’t implemented it until I have the rules working the way I want. The case is user place order under “orders” myID and waits for answer I’ll post in the same node. I want myID to be readable only by me and then if there’s a child with this user ID this user to be able to read this child, but only this one... The problem is I don’t know how to set this rule I thought the code I provided should work but it doesn’t let the user to read this node.

Comment: If the problem only exists in the simulator, edit your question to include a screenshot of the simulator with the path you're trying to read, and the auth status you're using.

Comment: Ok, I've added two screenshots.

Comment: When you use the simulator, it uses the actual data from your database to determine whether or not a read or write is allowed. The path you've input to the simulator doesn't look like it matches up to the one in your database.

Comment: When I read it using 123 like auth ID it works fine

Comment: The problem is now that the test in the simulator doesn't match up with the JSON data you showed earlier, making it impossible for us to mentally replay what the simulator is doing. Please edit your question to show the same JSON that the simulator is testing against (as text, no screenshot please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Sorry but I’m on the phone right now so I edit the question to be as clear as possible and I think I achieved it. Can’t post a real json data in the next few hours, but if you enter this one in the simulator it’l reproduce the result I obtain.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it setting these rules (note $id is nested in $uid):

```
{
  "rules": {
          "orders": {
          "$uid": {
            ".read": "auth.uid  === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
          "$id": {
            ".read": "auth.uid  === $id",
            ".write": "auth.uid === $id"
          },
          }
        }
  }
}
```

Previously I tought this line should do the work:

```
 ".read": "auth.uid  === $uid || root.child('orders').child($uid).child(auth.uid).exists()",
```